# Using DateTime::createFromFormat to convert the datepicker give me the wrong result

Tags: php, date, date-format

Good day here is my date format converter code

```
$sdate = $_POST['dtpicker']; 
$dtpicker = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $sdate);

if ($dtpicker === false) {
   echo 
   "<script LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
    window.alert('Date is Expire Please try again!');
    window.location.href='https://www.home.ae/online-form/';
    </script>";
}

$d = $dtpicker->format('Y-m-d');    
    
echo $d;
```

[Here is the date I enter from my site]
[1]:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/wiDQC.png

`$sdate = 12/29/2021`

The expect result should be
`2021-12-29`
but the result is

`2023-05-12`

any error in my code?
thank you guys

Comment: You're passing `m/d/Y`, not `d/m/Y`. There is no 29th month, so it's adding extra months to your date.

Comment: woah, this is the magic when their is a third person seeing your code, they can easily detect some error,.
thank you very much